# Django clean method based on condition (one form used in two views)

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I have one form which is used in two views. One to save and one edit/update. There is a clean function I use to check unique condition. (form has three fields. A combination of three can come only once.)

Now as I am using the same form, it checks this condition for both views -  Save and Edit. This results in form throwing an error in edit view stating that the value already exists.

How could I use this clean method in such a way that it will check for this validation for save view but will not check for edit view.

Edit View:

```
@login_required
def permissionEditView(request, pk):
    data = models.PermissionModel.objects.get(pk=pk)
    p_form = forms.PermissionForm(instance=data)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        p_form = forms.PermissionForm(request.POST, instance=data)
        if p_form.is_valid():
            p_form.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Permission updated successfully.')
            return redirect(companyProfileView)
    return render(request, 'company_profile.html', {'p_form': p_form})
```

Save view:

```
def permissionFormView(request):
    p_form = forms.PermissionForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        p_form = forms.PermissionForm(request.POST)
        if p_form.is_valid():
            p_form.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Permission added successfully.')
            return redirect(companyProfileView)
    return render(request, 'company_profile.html', {'p_form': p_form})
```

Form with clean method:

```
class PermissionForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = models.PermissionModel
        fields = '__all__'

    def clean(self):
        role = self.cleaned_data.get('role_name')
        feature = self.cleaned_data.get('feature')
        if models.PermissionModel.objects.filter(role_name=role, feature=feature).exists():
            raise forms.ValidationError('Permission exists.')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PermissionForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for field in self.fields:
            self.fields[field].widget.attrs = {'class': 'form-control form-control-sm'}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def clean(self):
        role = self.cleaned_data.get('role_name')
        feature = self.cleaned_data.get('feature')
        if not form.instance:
            if models.PermissionModel.objects.filter(role_name=role, feature=feature).exists():
                raise forms.ValidationError('Permission exists.')
```

you can check the instance in the clean method

Comment: Thank you for the idea. The code had to be slightly changed for me to get it working. I used it with self keyword ------- if not self.form.instance: Accepted for the idea.